# How to mark a verb in a sentence using spaCy? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, spacy

I want to mark verbs in sentences by adding an 'X' at the end of the verb word, like this `verbX`.

`SpaCy` assigns tags to sentence elements that Python does not index separately. For example, spaCy sees a bracket `(` or full stop behind a word `.` as a separate position, whereas Python does not. As a result, the index of the tags cannot be used to reliably insert the X into the sentence. The following function works by reconstructing the sentence from the tokens. However, it only allows me to insert the X at the start of the verb.

Is there a way to stick the X to the end of the verb word, like this `verbX` ? (With no whitespace between the verb and the X.)

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

s = "Dr. John (a fictional chartacter) never shakes hands."
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence':[s]})
k = df['sentence']

def marking(row):
    chunks = []
    for token in nlp(row):
        if token.tag_ == 'VBZ':
            chunks.append('X')
        chunks.append(token.text_with_ws)
    L = "".join(chunks)
    return L
x = k.apply(marking)
print(x)
```

This gives:

```
"Dr. John (a fictional chartacter) never Xshakes hands."
```

How can I get this?

```
"Dr. John (a fictional chartacter) never shakesX hands."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order in which you do your operations, to achieve your desired result it should be:

```
def marking(row):
    chunks = []
    for token in nlp(row):
        chunks.append(token.text_with_ws) #Append word first
        if token.tag_ == 'VBZ':
            chunks.append('X')            #Append 'X' second
    L = "".join(chunks)
    return L
```

To have the `'X'` attached directly to the verb moving any trailing whitespace to the end, use this logic:

```
def marking(row):
    chunks = []
    for token in nlp(row):
        if token.tag_ == 'VBZ':
            chunks.append(token.text + 'X' + token.whitespace_)
        else:
            chunks.append(token.text_with_ws)
    L = "".join(chunks)
    return L
```

Comment: Could you help me understand what this line does exactly? `chunks.append(token.text + 'X' + token.whitespace_)`. I mean, how does this line make it all work?

Comment: The `+` operator in python, when used between strings, concatenates them. This concatenates the text, the `X`, and any trailing whitespace the text may have, and appends the result to `chunks`.